# Using ELMo with Keras, how to correctly input the training set and labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, embedding

so I am trying to use Elmo with Keras, I used this Elmo code since it the only trainable one [Elmo](http://github.com/strongio/keras-elmo/blob/master/Elmo%20Keras.ipynb)

Using this Elmo, the embedding is integrated as a layer following the input layer, so the input layer is actually a string.  However, I am not sure how to put my output labels in model.fit(), should they be inputed as strings as well same structure as the input sentence (but that didn't work) or should they be 1 hot encoding, but if so how will the output label length match the input sentence length? any ideas?

Below is a snipped of my code, the error I get using the way I provide the labels and sample of the input and output labels (how they are provided)

```
input_word = layers.Input(shape=(1,), 
                        dtype="string",name='word_input')
input_pred = layers.Input(shape=(1,), 
                     dtype="string",name='pred_input')

embedding1 = ElmoEmbeddingLayer()(input_word)
embedding2 = ElmoEmbeddingLayer()(input_pred)

print('embedding 1 ',embedding1)
embeddingsCon = [embedding1, 
            embedding2]

con11 = keras.layers.concatenate(embeddingsCon)
print('con 11 ',con11)
DenseInjy= layers.Dense(1, activation='relu', name='Dense1')(con11)
print('DenseI',DenseI)


DenseI2= layers.Dense(15, activation='softmax', name='Dense2')(DenseI)

print('DenseI2',DenseI2)

modelI = Model([input_word, input_pred], DenseI2)
modelI.compile(optimizer='adam',
                           loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                           metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

modelI.fit([train_textEI,train_predIE], train_labelEI,
                       batch_size = 5,
                       epochs = 10 )
```

> Train_textEI[0]:[['Learning Center of The University of Lahore is established for the
> professional development of the teaching faculty and staff .']]
>
> Train_predEI[0]:[['established established established established established
> established established established established established
> established established established established established
> established established established established established']]
>
> Train_labelEI[['A0-B
> A0-I A0-I A0-I A0-I A0-I A0-I O P-B O A1-B A1-I A1-I A1-I A1-I A1-I
> A1-I A1-I A1-I O']] INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there
> are no variables in the graph to restore I0308 17:55:39.423806
> 140704918992768 saver.py:1483] Saver not created because there are no
> variables in the graph to restore result.shape ELMO (?, 1024)
>
> shape=(?, 1024), dtype=float32) con 11
> Tensor("concatenate_12/concat:0", shape=(?, 2048), dtype=float32)
> DenseI Tensor("Dense1_10/Relu:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
> DenseI2 Tensor("Dense2_6/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 15), dtype=float32)

The error:Error when checking target: expected Dense2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (2905, 1, 1) I think it has something to do with the how the labels are fit in the model

Answer (score 0):

train_textEI should be a Numpy array of strings, not a list of strings. Try this:

```
train_textEI = np.array(train_textEI, dtype=object)
```